# What is the best database structure In this scenario?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

I'm working on a program in C# that will eventually read and write data to and from a database. I was thinking of using Microsoft SQL Server because from what I read, connectivity with C# is easy and efficient. However, I am unsure as to how to set up and structure the database with the information I will need it to store.

The data involves a unique person that has a series of intervals which have a series of properties. For example, a person "Bob" who has been in the system for six months will have two intervals, one for three months and then one for six months. The three months interval will have, for example, a list of hobbies that the person does, amongst other things, that may differ from the six months interval. Programmatically, I can easily represent these things using dictionaries, lists, and ADTs, but converting that into a database is hard to wrap my head around.

The only way I can think of doing it is to have each value in each list as a separate record, but I am skeptical about this approach. I feel like it isn't the best way to do things.

So for example, I'd have a person table that would look like this:

```
Name, Age, DOB
```

And then an Interval table that would look like this:

```
Name, Three Months
Name, Six Months
```

And then a hobbies table like this:

```
Name, Three Months, Bike Riding
Name, Three Months, Coding
Name, Six Months, Bike Riding
Name, Six Months, Coding
Name, Six Months, Basketball
```

I feel like this will grow way too quickly, especially when there's an expected one thousand plus different people all with their own intervals.

If anyone can shed some of their wisdom or personal experiences, it would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You desperately need to read up on normalization. You do NOT want to store the name in more than 1 table. Consider how ridiculous it would be if somebody changes their name. Also consider how horrible it is that you can't have more than 1 person with the same name. You also need at LEAST one more table to hold the hobbies. Then you need a bridge table to hold the many-to-many relationship between hobbies and intervals. You probably also have a many-to-many between people and intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to have five tables.

Person:
Id, Name, Age, DOB.

Interval:
Id, Name (of interval)

IntervalPerson:
Id, personIdFK, intervalIdFK

Hobbies:
Id, Name (of hobby)

HobbieIntervalPerson
Id, intervalPersonIdFK, hobbyIdFK

This way all your tables will be normalized (which will save you a lot of headaches down the line) and you will be able to store the data in a structured way.

Also, to address your concern about the number of records that will be generated given the fact that you expect 1000+ people. I wouldn't worry about it, that's a really small amount of records for modern databases so I don't expect a noticeable performance impact.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work:

The person table sounds good along with a hobby table.  Now you just need a joiner that joins people to hobbies, Like Person_Hobby.

Instead of having a record for each interval, just put a dates like:

- Effective
- Expiration

In the joiner table.  This allows to get person hobbies for *any* interval.

Then you could have a look up table that has all your intervals.

Interval 1 - 1/1/2016 to 3/1/2016

Then one can use those dates as criteria against your Person_Hobby table to get the hobbies for that interval.  So, instead of each interval having a record, each record defines the interval.  Multiple records would be required if say the hobby expired and then the person took it up again a year later.  But that might work for you.